# How to export my interactive r map to a clickable file?

Tags: javascript, r, leaflet, interactive, rmaps

There is a huge variety of r packages for interactive/dynamic maps out there, like [leaftlet](http://leafletjs.com) or [rMaps](http://rmaps.github.io) etc. However, I am struggling to understand if and how I can export my interactive maps to a file, like .html or .js, which I than can sent to another person, which only has to click on the index.html or starter file and can open the interactive map in a browser (without downloading additional software)?

Comment: use [`htmlwidgets::saveWidget()`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/htmlwidgets/htmlwidgets.pdf) for saving an html widget. This should work with any [`htmlwidget`](http://gallery.htmlwidgets.org/)

Comment: Thx, that has helped me.